# re coating a patch of wooden flooring

Tags: repair, hardwood-floor, refinishing

my lease is about to come up and i have to patch up my floor if i want to see my deposit back.  the coating on the floor feels like polyurethane, or a thin lacquer, i cannot tell which.  [image]

you can see the spot in the picture.

the spot  (area B in the picture above) was caused by a wooden chair without proper footing scrapping against the boards.  the area you see is where the wood feels raw and unsanded, with the coat of finishing gradually coming on around said area.

can i doctor up this one patch?  will i need to pry up the floor? How do i accurately tell the kind of coating on the floor?  if i can fix just the patch,  how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Your title says "PE" floor.  AFAIK, that means "engineered" flooring, but your photo shows something that looks like natural wood.  Can you clarify and confirm what the flooring is?

Comment: @feetwet I thought PE was short for PolyEurathane.

Comment: Definitely not.  When describing wood flooring it's a trade abbreviation for "Precision Engineered."  In plastics it stands for Polyethylene, and I haven't heard of any polyethylene-based wood finishes.  The common wood finish is spelled polyurethane.  And it would be weird to assert it's finished in polyurethane in the title given that a big part of your question is that you don't know what the finish is.

Comment: @feetwet oh....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an attempt to try to answer your question there are a couple of important additional pieces of information needed. This request for clarification is being put in answer space because there is no provision for showing a picture in the comment space.

1. First off need to know what caused the damage in the first place. Please be accurate as possible.
2. Secondly the photo shows a surprising number of defects in the floor which I have labeled as A to F in the picture below. What area are you thinking needs fixing?

Answers to these items are going to greatly inform useful answers that you are likely to get.

[image]

Comment: area B. ill get the rest later

Comment: alright.  i added more details.  i will add more as needed!